# Unable to perform near conditional jump in MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Please adbice,
I'm beating my head against the wall the whole day:
What is wrong with this code? Whu MASM gives errors?

```
LookupLoop:
        and ecx, edx
        movzx   ecx, word ptr [edi + ecx*2]
        cmp ecx, ebp
        lea ebx, LeaveNowProxy
       js ebx ;;;This is it. Here it fails.
        jmp LeaveNowProxyEnd
 LeaveNowProxy:
        jmp LeaveNow
 LeaveNowProxyEnd:
 LoopEntry:  movzx   eax, word ptr [esi + ecx - 1]
         cmp eax, ebx
```

It says: >....\masmx86\match686.asm(357): error A2077: instruction does not allow NEAR indirect addressing. I tried to lea to register and then pass the register, then I have done this proxy jump, then i tried js cs:ebx sythax. Everythime i get almost the smae error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
lea ebx, LeaveNowProxy
js ebx
```

with

```
js LeaveNowProxy
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe that register-based conditional jumps are supported.

Instead you can try

```
  jns skip
  jmp ebx
skip:
```

Comment: The same effect

```LookupLoop:
        and ecx, edx
        movzx   ecx, word ptr [edi + ecx*2]
        cmp ecx, ebp
        jns DontLeaveLeaveNowProxyEnd
  jmp LoopEntry
DontLeaveLeaveNowProxyEnd:
  jmp LeaveNow
LoopEntry:  movzx   eax, word ptr [esi + ecx - 1]
        cmp eax, ebx
        jnz short LookupLoop
        mov eax, [window]
        movzx   eax, word ptr [eax + ecx]
        cmp eax, [scanstart]
        jnz short LookupLoop
;;; Store the current value of chainlen.

        mov [chainlenwmask], edx```

Comment: Hey bud, I a bit remade jumpings almost in a way like you proposed - these errors gone. 10x.